# Laravel whereRelation() not filtring the query

Tags: php, laravel

I need to select all offers where the merchant has status open and dd_merchant set to 1. The match between merchant and offer is done using a col named mid.

In my offer model I have the following:

```
public function merchants()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Merchant::class,'mid','mid');
}
```

My query looks like this:

```
 $data['offers']= Offer::whereRelation('merchants', 'status', 'Open')
      ->whereRelation('merchants', 'dd_merchant', '1')
      ->where('status', '=', 'Loaded')
      ->where("start", "<=", date("Y-m-d"))
      ->where("end", ">=", date("Y-m-d"))
      ->where('category', '=', $request->category)
      ->orderBy('title','ASC')
      ->paginate(20);
```

For the sake of this test, I have one merchant set to status 'Closed' and has dd_merchant set to 0 in the database.

The query returned by this is

```
select * from `offers` where (exists (select * from `merchants` where `offers`.`mid` = `merchants`.`mid` and `status` = 'Open' and `merchants`.`deleted_at` is null) and exists (select * from `merchants` where `offers`.`mid` = `merchants`.`mid` and `dd_merchant` = '1' and `merchants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `status` = 'Loaded' and `start` <= '2022-10-03' and `end` >= '2022-10-03' ) and `offers`.`deleted_at` is null order by `title` asc limit 20 offset 0
```

For some reason, I am still getting offers from that merchant with the above query. Am I assuming wrong that whereRelation() filters the offers based on the condition on the second table? If so, how can I achieve my goal?

In one of the 27 variants of this I tried so fare, I used the wherehas() like this:

```
            $data['offers']= Offer::
                whereHas('merchants', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->where('dd_merchant', '=', '1')->where('status', '=', 'Open');
                })
                ->where('status', '=', 'Loaded')
                ->where("start", "<=", date("Y-m-d"))
                ->where("end", ">=", date("Y-m-d"))
                ->where('category', '=', $request->category)
                ->orderBy('title','ASC')
                ->paginate(20);
```

The above made a lot more sense to me but I get the same result ... I get offers that should not be there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would use `DB::enableQueryLog()` before the query starts and run `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` after query is done to see the resulting (mysql) query. Once you have that, you can copy the query to a mysql editor and see which part of the query should be fixed. I always approach it like this and have solved 100% of my query issues :)

Comment: Since you have 2 conditions on the same relation i would go for `whereHas()`

Comment: @RobBiermann good tip, However I use the Laravel debugbar where i can see all queries.

Comment: I got the following query. 

select * from `offers` where (exists (select * from `merchants` where `offers`.`mid` = `merchants`.`mid` and `status` = 'Open' and `merchants`.`deleted_at` is null) and exists (select * from `merchants` where `offers`.`mid` = `merchants`.`mid` and `dd_merchant` = '1' and `merchants`.`deleted_at` is null) and `status` = 'Loaded' and `start` <= '2022-10-03' and `end` >= '2022-10-03' ) and `offers`.`deleted_at` is null order by `title` asc limit 20 offset 0

Looks like a valid query and when I post it in PHPMyAdmin I don't get the offers for the merchant. Weird!

Comment: @PatrickSimard, please add the query to your question, it makes reading it so much more easy :)

Comment: Thanks! I think I spot your issue and it is related to what @GertB. was saying. You want to ask 1 merchant 2 questions by using `whereHas()`. Currently you are asking if the offer has a merchant with status open AND has a merchant with dd_merchant = 1. In your case this could be 2 different merchants, therefore you are getting false positives :)

Comment: I started off by using whereHas() but I got the same result. Let me update my question above

Comment: I think you should validate your data, as your query seems fitting, but it all depends on your data. Does the one result that should NOT be shown, have a merchant with `dd_merchant = 1` and merchant `status = open`? Since you are not specifying a merchant, any merchant with those statements true will cause the offer to be shown. Maybe you can take that oil change `Offer` result, with the merchant relation and do `dd($offer->toArray())`. I hope it is clear what I mean

Comment: @PatrickSimard replace first four lines and see.  `Offer::query()->with(['merchants'])
        ->where('dd_merchant', static function ($query) {
            $query->where('dd_merchant', '=', '1')
                ->where('status', '=', 'Open');
        })`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam tried what you suggested and got the following error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dd_merchant' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `offers` where (`dd_merchant` = (select * where `dd_merchant` = 1 and `status` = Open) and `status` = Loaded and `start` <= 2022-10-03 and `end` >= 2022-10-03 and `title` LIKE %% or `name` LIKE %%) and `offers`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: @RobBierman I added DB screenshots. the first one is the merchant set to Closed and dd-Merchant 0 and the second one is the offer row. Based on the SQL query the offer should not be selected.

Comment: So what was it ?:)